# Django - Upload PDF and Excel file to mysql database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-uploads

I have written a code to upload an excel sheet and save the contents to mysql database. Below is the code to upload the file in memory.

```
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    file_in_memory = request.FILES['file'].read()
    wb = load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(file_in_memory), data_only=True)
```

Now, I want to upload a PDF file and save the path to mysql database using the same function. For instance, If excel has record A then there is an associated PDF file which I have to link. How do I handle this situation? Using formset is a solution? I am aware of multi-file upload but I assume that will save the file path to the database directly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this directly in a `model.py` using `FileField`.

```
from django.db import models
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    file_in_memory=models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt for your response. But this will allow me to upload only one file correct? As of now, I am not saving the excel sheet to the disk. Just reading the contents.But I want to save PDF to the disk.

Comment: You can upload as many as you want from a view. This model allows you to store any number of file records in your database using Django.

Comment: So I am currently not using Models because I don't want the excel to be saved. It should read the content while in the memory. Therefore I have included this class in views.py `class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
   file = forms.FileField()` This code will read the file in memory.  `if request.method == "POST":
                form = UploadFileForm(request.POST,
                                      request.FILES)
                if form.is_valid():
                    file_in_memory = request.FILES['file'].read()`